# Сохраняем xml теги svg и /svg в файл somefile.svg

Tags: xml, svg, html

Добрый день, всем пользователям Хэшкод!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - есть html страница, в нее встроена SVG графика (XML), как мне сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопке "Сохранить SVG файл", то что находится между тегами `<svg>` и `</svg>` сохранялось в файл somefile.svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправить на сервер то что находиться в `svg`, На `jquery`, например, так:

```
$.ajax({url:'save_data_url', data:$('svg').html()}).success(function(data){location=data;});
```

)

А сервер вернёт ссылку на закачку.

Сохранить в файл только средствами `js` или `html` не получится из-за политики безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо, а затем с помощью PHP скрипта сохраняю выборку jQuery ($('svg').html()) в файл somefile.svg в бинарном режиме?

Comment: Можно и так, только зачем в бинарном то?